# Previous state of timer is not cleared

Tags: java, android, time, countdowntimer

I am trying to update a text view with time elapsed since a button was pressed, following is my code:

```
      public void startTimeCounter() {
        tripTimeCounter = new CountDownTimer(60 * 1000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            repeatCounter = repeatCounter + 1;
            startTimeCounter();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            timedisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            timedisplay.setText(formatInterval((repeatCounter * 60) * 1000
                    - millisUntilFinished));

        }

    }.start();
}

private static String formatInterval(final long l) {
    final long hr = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(l);
    final long min = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l
            - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hr));
    final long sec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(l
            - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hr) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(min));
    final long ms = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(l
            - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hr) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(min)
            - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(sec));
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hr, min, sec, 0);
}
```

The timer works perfectly, however when I press the button for the second time the value in the text view is not cleared, but instead a new time is associated which runs in parallel with the previous timer, I can see the previous time and a reflection of the new time incrementing simultaneously . I want to know as to how will I clear the previous state, before a second call is made to startTimeCounter();

The button Click Code:

```
   private View.OnClickListener but = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (isOnline() == true) {
            // PHP();
            // network();

            startTimeCounter();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Not connected to the internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

public class XXX 
{
    private CountDownMine CountDown;

```
private class CountDownMine extends CountDownTimer 
{
    public CountDownMine(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) 
    {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() 
    {
        //The same yours
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
    {
        //The same yours
    }   
}


private View.OnClickListener but = new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
        if (isOnline() == true) 
        {
            //Code  

    if(CountDown != null)
        CountDown.cancel();

    CountDown = new CountDownMine(60 * 1000, 1000);
    CountDown.start();
    } 
    else 
    {
        //Code
    }
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
       public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            repeatCounter = repeatCounter + 1;
            startTimeCounter();
        }
```

You are creating a `new counter` every time `previous one finishes` or the `button is clicked`. That is the problem. Keep the `CountDownTimer` instance outside your startTimeCounter method and try passing it to `startTimeCounter(CountDownTimer tripTimeCounter)` and restart the timer onFinish() instead,

```
        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            repeatCounter = repeatCounter + 1;
            this.start();
            }
```

### EDIT:

```
private View.OnClickListener but = new View.OnClickListener() {

        tripTimeCounter = new CountDownTimer(60 * 1000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            repeatCounter = repeatCounter + 1;
            startTimeCounter();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            timedisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            timedisplay.setText(formatInterval((repeatCounter * 60) * 1000
                    - millisUntilFinished));

        }

    };

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (isOnline() == true) {
            // PHP();
            // network();

            tripTimeCounter.start();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Not connected to the internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Its still tripping with the previous values!

Comment: I am sure what the problem is. Updated answer.

Comment: Still tripping! I am unsure of the problem actually

Comment: Please check the edited Question above, I have included the button click code at the bottom.

Comment: You have to pass CountDownTimer instance to your startTimeCounter() method!

Comment: I am getting NPE if I do that! That is why I am unable to determine what the actual problem is!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34424/discussion-between-rocketboy-and-user2613996)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `CountDownTimer` every time `startTimeCounter` is called. Restart the previous one instead:

```
// Initializing the timer earier
CountdownTimer tripTimeCounter = new CountDownTimer(60 * 1000, 1000) {
    ...
}
```

The timer starting method becomes:

```
public void startTimeCounter() {
    tripTimeCounter.cancel();
    tripTimeCounter.start();
}
```

Comment: No, still tripping with the previous values

Comment: @user2613996 are you really sure you do not have a "new CountDownTimer()" call made anywhere resulting from the button click?

Comment: @user2613996 looking at the source of CountDownTimer, looks like you may need to call `tripTimeCounter.cancel()` before the restart

Comment: Yes its actually a recursive function!

Comment: @user2613996 did you try the updated version with `cancel()`?

Comment: It gives me a NPE, please note the scenario I am using this in, I think for that to work I will have to set a flag.

Comment: @user2613996 huh? if you get NPE for `tripTimeCounter.cancel()`, it means you have *not* initialized `tripTimeCounter` earlier, like I said.